# VMC Push error on Cloudfoundry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud-foundry

I have installed CloudFoundry on Ubuntu and tried to push a sample helloworld application. I am getting the below exception. Can anyone faced the same issue. Please let me know how to resolve this problem. Springs applications are pushed correctly but this exception is raised when I push rails or sinatra applications.

```
root@CFDemo1:~/helloworld# vmc push myapp03
Would you like to deploy from the current directory? [Yn]:
Application Deployed URL: 'myapp03.vcap.me'?
Detected a Sinatra Application, is this correct? [Yn]:
Memory Reservation [Default:128M] (64M, 128M, 256M, 512M, 1G or 2G)
Creating Application: OK
Would you like to bind any services to 'myapp03'? [yN]:
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Processing resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (0K): OK
Push Status: OK
Staging Application: OK
Starting Application: .
Error: Application [myapp03] failed to start, logs information below.

====> /logs/staging.log <====

Logfile created on 2011-08-02 16:56:28 +0530 by logger.rb/25413
Adding rack-1.3.1.gem to app...
Adding sinatra-1.2.6.gem to app...
Adding tilt-1.3.2.gem to app...
Adding bundler-1.0.10.gem to app...

====> logs/stderr.log <====

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/ruby: 
  No such file or directory -- ./rubygems/ruby/1.8/bin/bundle (LoadError)
```

Comment: I had the same issue and gave up. I think it might be related to gems, e.g. you must include thin in your gemfile

Comment: Can you include your Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved in the latest Cloud Foundry source at http://github.com/cloudfoundry